# node_modules are not installed on heroku

Tags: heroku, npm, dependencies, bower, node-modules

Below are two packages and I am trying to push my project to heroku with them, console saying that npm and node are installed on server but when I clone the project there is no node_modules directory in the project. 'bower install' in package.json saying bower is not found. When I remove 'bower install' no dependency is installed on server when pushed, though console writes them down as installed they're not installed on server when I open browser console.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "meal-order",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "This is an app for ordering meal",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.5",
    .....(other angular -libs)
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-connect": "^3.0.9",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "bower": "1.7.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^5.11.1",
    "npm": "^3.8.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  },
```

bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.5.5",
.....(other angular -libs)
"express": "^4.14.0",
"gulp": "^3.8.8",
"gulp-connect": "^3.0.9",
"ionicons": "^3.0.0",
"protractor": "^3.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"main": "gulpfile.js",
"license": "ISC",
"moduleType": [
    "node"
],
```

.gitignore:

```
/node_modules/*
node_modules/*
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

This is the error I get on console:

```
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > meal-order@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_3ac183217c4c79ebe98cbb69eecb36de
remote:        > bower install
remote:        
remote:        sh: 1: bower: not found
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because you've defined `bower` in your `devDependencies` object in `package.json`. When you push to Heroku, it will not install things listed in `devDependencies`, so you need to have bower listed in your normal `dependencies` object =)

Comment: Moving `bower` to dependencies doesn't change anything I am facing the same problem again

Comment: This helped me! For me it was the `node-sass` package, and I moved it from devDependencies to dependencies, and my deploy succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install **devDependencies**, add the following in the config vars in heroku.

> key = NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION value = false

If you are using command line execute the following command

> heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#devdependencies

Comment: It doesn't change anything, the same problem

Comment: do you have node as your build pack, and please check in the one-off dyno to know the project structure as you gitignored node_modules you may not find it when you clone the project

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno, from your cmd try  "heroku run bash" and then "ls" to view your project structure in your heroku app.